# EntityFramework.xml and EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml - what's their purpose?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using a project the references EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll; I've always wondered why, whenever I Build (in Release mode) it always produces 2 xml files in the \bin\release directory...

I have never deployed these xml files, and looks like they are useless for deployment purposes. So what do these two files do?

Comment: That is the XML documentation file that is generated for assemblies containing whatever valid XML doco has been written. I.e. the `///<summary>` tags etc. These don't need to be included in deployments. You can turn them on for your own assemblies under the Project Properties under "Build" then ticking "XML documentation file".

Comment: why a comment, I'll take that as an answer Steve; interesting to know I can turn them on for my own assemblies (been too busy to care up until now).